# How to execute one command as root, another command as different user in one RUN statement

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, sudo, docker-build

I need to execute some commands as root and some commands as different user when building image. All of the commands should be executed inside of one RUN statement to preserve a background service created by the first command. I tried:

```
USER root     
RUN sudo -i -u postgres "pg_ctl -w start" \
  && cd /home/backend && npm run server & sleep 50 \
  && cd /home/frontend && npm run test
```

It gives me error:

```
-bash: pg_ctl -w start: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo -i -u postgres "pg_ctl -w start"   && cd /home/backend && npm run server & sleep 50 && cd /home/frontend && npm run test' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

If I do:

```
USER postgres
RUN pg_ctl -w start \
  && cd /home/backend && npm run server & sleep 50 \
  && cd /home/frontend && npm run test
```

Everything works fine. So, what is the problem with previous code?

The Dockerfile is created from node:12.18.0 which is based on Debian 9.

Comment: This seems like you're trying to run a multi-container integration test inside the Dockerfile.  I wouldn't do this at all.  Use a tool like Docker Compose to start the database and backend containers, then run `npm run test` from the host system outside Docker to launch the test.

Comment: @DavidMaze huge thanks for this suggestion. I guess I can run backend, db containers, and testing container that has entrypoint `sleep 50 && npm run test` inside docker compose. Then do `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes, the executable is `pg_ctl` not `pg_ctl -w start`.

```
RUN sudo -i -u postgres pg_ctl -w start \
```

> what is the problem with previous code?

The same as if you would do:

```
RUN "pg_ctl -w start" \
```

Comment: After removing quotes, it says `-bash: pg_ctl: command not found`

Comment: Then `pg_ctl` is not in `PATH`. Check the output of `type pg_ctl` or `which pg_ctl` and add the path to `PATH` to use the full path to executable.

Comment: I just don't understand why it is in the `PATH` when using `USER postgres` and `RUN pg_ctl -w start`, but not in the `PATH` when using `RUN sudo -i -u postgres pg_ctl -w start`